# Delete an entire Joomla website and redirect all links to new non-joomla website

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, joomla, url-rewriting

I just deleted my joomla website.

I have a new website ready to upload on the same server. This new website is  html5 with extensions ( .shtml )

My problem is I need to redirect all the old joomla pages/links to the new shtml pages. Then rewrite those urls to remove extensions.

example: (JOOMLA SITE) http://www.blah.com/contact  to   (NEW SITE) http://blah.com/contact.shtml

But joomla is cms, so htaccess didn't work for me. Or, I'm doing it wrong. This is where I'm stuck.

I've tried these so far in the htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301 /contact http://www.blah.com/contact.sthml

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blah.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blah.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: did the first rule not work ? Redirect 301 /contact http://www.blah.com/contact.sthml

Comment: It did not, no. I tested it while I had the Joomla website, uploaded the new webpage, did the redirect and it did not work. And then I deleted the website, tested it again and it still didn't work. :(

Comment: How long does redirect take to work? I must of waited 5 hours and cleared my cache.

Comment: It's instant, htaccess is never cached, it is run every time a page is requested.

Comment: also, you might want to use 302 (temporary redirect) until you get it right, since redirects are cached browser-side

Comment: I see, when I tested the 301 redirects in my htaccess file before I deleted my website, all the links still went to the old website. I could try a 302 and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If your using .shtml then I'm wondering what is running on your webserver. Is your server is running Apache? Hatccess rules are only read by Apache.

> But joomla is cms, so htaccess didn't work for me

That is irrelevant, you are trying to redirect one url to another it doesn't matter what generated those pages. Besides, Joomla uses .htaccess anyway.

Comment: Yep, my server is running apache. 2.0. I'm not sure what's up quite yet. I'm going to try more with the htaccess and test links to see if they work. I'll update here when I get results or I get stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. It was weird. I reinstalled joomla 2.5 and added a redirect plugin. Then I used that to redirect the old links to my new website and it was done.

I'm not sure why the .htaccess method didn't work, but there you go.

Thanks everyone for their answers and support.